# Javascript ajax is showing the same message even if no more records

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My javascript/ajax is working fine but when there is no more records it is showing the same message as if there are more records.

I tried moving the code around but i cannot succeed.
Need your kind help

```
<div id="results"></div>
<div id="loader_image"><img src="images/loader.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24"> Loading...please wait</div>
<div class="margin10"></div>
<div id="loader_message"></div>
```

```
var busy = false;
var limit = 5;
var offset = 0;

function displayRecords(lim, off) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "getresult.php",
    data: "limit=" + lim + "&offset=" + off,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
$("#loader_message").html("").hide();
$('#loader_image').show();
    },
    success: function(html) {
$("#results").append(html);
$('#loader_image').hide();
if (html == "" || html == null) {
  $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">No more records.</button>').show();
} else {
              $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Loading please wait...</button>').show();
}
window.busy = false;
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (busy == false) {
    busy = true;
    displayRecords(limit, offset);
  }

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#results").height() && !busy) {
busy = true;
offset = limit + offset;
            displayRecords(limit, offset);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: perhaps `html == "" || html == null` is never true! have you checked?

Comment: `html` will likely be undefined if there is no response body. `if (typeof html === 'undefined')`

Comment: Try: `if ((html || "") === "")`

Comment: @JaromandaX it doesnt work

Comment: @freedomn-m it didnot work also

Comment: Most likely because `html` is *not* empty

Comment: @freedomn-m any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, return an empty string from your php

Comment: what do you mean "it doesn't work"? I suggested checking what `html` is, for example `console.log(html)` and seeing the content  - I didn't suggest a solution, I suggested a debugging tip

Comment: You may also like to use `console.log("[" + html +"]")` as empty strings can be hard to see in the console.

Answer (score -1):

Try this inside success function:

```
if(html !== null){
  $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Loading 
  please wait...</button>').show();
  $("#results").append(html);
} else {
   $("#loader_message").html('<button class="btn btn-default" type="button">No more 
   records.</button>').show();
}
```